# optimal sampling design

Tags: sampling, biostatistics

Due to budget limitation for maternity identification of individuals in one brood (offspring from single host), there are two approaches: one is to identifying all individuals of fewer replicate broods, another  to take a sample from each brood from more replicate broods. According to the central limit theorem, the later is preferable. I am not sure which is optimal to obtain the maternity among individuals in a brood.

Comment: Could you give some more details, and explication for all the non-biologists on this site? How many broods, potentially? typical size? How many identifications can you do? Knowing some of this, one way to answer (for yourself) is to do some simple simulations!

Comment: I very much doubt that the CLT says anything (directly) on which sampling method is preferable.  Can you please explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: I have 20 broods each containing  ca 80 offspring parasites produced by 2 females on one shared host. I have developed the molecular marker for maternal identification, but I am not able to examine all offspring. I have to take a small sample from each brood,  a larger sample from some broods, or examine all of offspring from a few broods. I am wondering which approach is preferable to make reliable inference of maternity  in a brood.